# Resizing a image with PHP and GD2. I'm getting the image and a black background

Tags: php, gd, gd2

I'm creating a dynamic class to generate various images.

**ImagesUtils.php**

```
<?php
class ImagesUtils
{
    private $nombre_imagen = null;
    private $imagen = null;
    private $extension = null;
    private $directorio = null;

    private $width = null;
    private $height = null;
    private $tipo = null;

    private $final_width = null;
    private $final_height = null;
    private $nuevo_nombre = null;
    private $nuevo_directorio = null;

    public function __construct($imagen, $directorio = '')
    {
        $this->directorio = realpath("..".DS."data".DS."storage".DS."files".DS.$directorio);

        $this->imagen = $this->directorio.DS.$imagen;
        $this->nombre_imagen = $imagen;

        $this->extension = substr($imagen, strrpos($imagen, '.') + 1, strlen($imagen));

        $propiedades = getimagesize($this->imagen);

        $this->width = $propiedades["0"];
        $this->height = $propiedades["1"];
        $this->tipo = $propiedades["2"];
    }

    public function Resize($width = null, $height = null, $proporcion = true)
    {
        $this->final_width = $width;
        $this->final_height = $height;

        if(true == $proporcion)
            self::proporcion($width, $height);

        $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->imagen);

        $nueva_imagen = imagecreatetruecolor($this->final_width, $this->final_height);

        imagecopyresampled($nueva_imagen, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->final_width, $this->final_height, $this->width, $this->height);

        return imagejpeg($image, $this->nueva_imagen);
    }
}
?>
```

And how I call:

```
$procesar_imagen = new ImagesUtils($imagen["nombre"]);
$procesar_imagen->Resize(640, 480);
```

Width this code works fine... but if I use this:

```
$procesar_imagen->Resize(300, 300);
```

My final image generated looks like: http://i51.tinypic.com/htwx79.jpg

The input image is: http://i51.tinypic.com/15n9ifc.jpg

I don't know how to solve it... my proporcion() function returns the new height and width from the aspect ratio of the photo... I checked and the values are right, the width returned is 300 (and the final image width is 300... but counting the black area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're trying to write your own code, but you might want to have a look at this: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php